# updating variable given a condition

Tags: javascript, variables

Could someone please explain to me why the value of my sum2 variable is 0? I was expecting it to be 1.

```
var colors = [1,2,3,4,5];
var DEFINITIONS = [[1],[2],[3]];

function getAttributes(colors){
    var sumSaturated = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    colors.forEach(function(hsl) {
        if(hsl>2){
            sumSaturated ++;
            for(var x = 0; x<DEFINITIONS.length; x++){
                if(DEFINITIONS[x]===hsl){
                    sum2++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(sum2, sumSaturated);
}

getAttributes(colors);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is strange.  var DEFINITIONS = [[1],[2],[3]];  Is this part of your homework?

Comment: yes, it's homework :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're comparing `hsl`, which appears to be a number, to an array. You're effectively doing this:

```
hsl === [1]
hsl === [2]
hsl === [3]
```

If you want to compare against the individual numbers, either redefine `DEFINITIONS`

```
var DEFINITIONS = [1, 2, 3];
```

Or compare against the first element in it

```
DEFINITIONS[x][0] === hsl
```

Comment: thank you, just been staring at this for too long... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`DEFINITIONS` is an array of arrays. you need `if(DEFINITIONS[x][0]===hsl){`

```
var colors = [1,2,3,4,5];
var DEFINITIONS = [[1],[2],[3]];

function getAttributes(colors){
    var sumSaturated = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    colors.forEach(function(hsl) {
        if(hsl>2){
            sumSaturated ++;
            for(var x = 0; x<DEFINITIONS.length; x++){
                if(DEFINITIONS[x][0]===hsl){
                    sum2++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(sum2, sumSaturated);
}

getAttributes(colors);
```